# Spark streaming store method only work in Duration window but not in foreachRDD workflow in customized receiver

Tags: scala, apache-spark, redis, spark-streaming

I define a receiver to read data from Redis.

part of receiver simplified code:

```
class MyReceiver extends Receiver (StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY){
  override def onStart() = {
    while(!isStopped) {
      val res = readMethod()
      if (res != null) store(res.toIterator) 
      // using res.foreach(r => store(r)) the performance is almost the same
    }
  }
}
```

My streaming workflow:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, new Duration(50))
val myReceiver = new MyReceiver()
val s = ssc.receiverStream(myReceiver)
s.foreachRDD{ r => 
  r.persist()
  if (!r.isEmpty) {
    some short operations about 1s in total
    // note this line ######1
  }
}
```

I have a producer which produce much faster than consumer so that there are plenty records in Redis now, I tested with number 10000. I debugged, and all records could quickly be read after they are in Redis by `readMethod()` above. However, **in each microbatch I can only get 30 records**. (If store is fast enough it should get all of 10000)

With this suspect, I added a sleep 10 seconds code `Thread.sleep(10000)` to `######1` above. **Each microbatch still gets about 30 records**, and each microbatch process time increases 10 seconds. And if I increase the Duration to 200ms, `val ssc = new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, new Duration(200))`, it could get about 120 records.

All of these shows spark streaming only generate RDD in `Duration`? After gets RDD and in main workflow, `store` method is temporarily stopped? But this is a great waste if it is true. I want it also generates RDD (store) while the main workflow is running.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot leave a comment simply I don't have enough reputation. Is it possible that property`spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate` is set somewhere in your code ?

Comment: There is no such config is set, and logically this may not be the issue, because the issue here is not the low rate, but when the streaming is processing, the store method is not working

Comment: Well even tough the numbers are very small, with Duration(50), you had 30 records. Also, you are saying that with Duration(200) you had 120 records. After seeing the correlation I thought maybe that you had the properly set.

Comment: I think this may be correlated to data size. My record is encoded array of size 100,000 float32 approximately. So this may be too large for it to store? However, structured streaming does not have this problem.